# Verbs that can be changed into passive contruction?

Tags: passive-voice, transitivity, active-voice

A **transitive verb** that **expresses an action** can be transformed into passive construction. For example, "The boys *carried* the piano into the house" can be revised into "The piano was carried by the boys into the house". And a **transitive** verbs that **expresses a state** cannot be transformed into passive constructions. For example "He *has* a new car" cannot be revised into "A new car was had by him."

In addition, an "intransitive verb +preposition" that **can be followed by an object and express an action** can be transformed into passive construction. For example, "Someone broke into my house last week" can be revised into "My house was broken into last week". And an "intransitive verb +preposition" that **can be followed by an object and express a state** cannot be transformed into passive constructions such as "This book belong to me" cannot be revised into "I was belonged to by the book".

In conclusion,  a **transitive verb** and an "intransitive verb +preposition" that **express an action and can be followed by an object** can be transformed into passive construction. So it is not accurate to say that transitive verbs have passive constructions while intransitive verbs don't. Am I right?

Comment: "I walked from my home." ?"My home was walked from."

Comment: What is wrong with "A new car was had by him."? The object (of the active voice phrase) becomes the subject, and the verb becomes an aux. form of *to be* + a past participle.

Comment: @user3169 I think most native speakers would find that sentence ungrammatical. It seems equivalent to the stative uses of: *A pretty face was had by Joan. *Five dollars are had by me. By contrast, dynamic: Sandwiches were had by all. A good time was had by all. (Even in dynamic sense, there are no-gos: *A nap was had by me. *A baby was had by the woman.)

Answer (score 1):

*[Break into](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/break-into?q=break%20into)* is a transitive verb. This is what the Merriam-Webster Unabridged says. Other dictionaries seem to differ, but *in this answer* the verb will be used in a transitive sense.

[image: <code>M-W break into</code>]

Specifically, it is a **prepositional verb** because the verb + preposition make one meaning-unit. (A *prepositional verb* is **not** a *phrasal verb,* even if some dictionaries wrongly list *break into* with phrasal verbs. (There are tests to distinguish the two types of verbs; I don't want to overlong this answer with them, but I can provide).

**Without an object**, the sentence is incomplete and thus ungrammatical:

*ungrammatical without an object:*
*He broke into.

*grammatical forms*:

*active*:
He *broke into* the house

*passive*:
The house *was broken into* by him.

Note the sense of *action* or *motion* or *direction* (He broke *into* the house).

Notice that *break into* **cannot always** be used in the passive. It is precisely when the verb does not have a sense of *motion/action* that this is the case.

He *broke into* a sweat.

*A sweat was broken into by him.

The audience *broke into* applause.

*Applause was *broken into* by the audience.

*A gallop was *broken into* by the horse

Last, another transitive verb, composed of one word, can substutute for *break into*: *burgle*. (Note there are no exact synonyms and let's not get into legal definitions.)